# Is there a way to apply an arbitrary condition to a MongoDB aggregation?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a MongoDB database where people can enter relatively arbitrary search conditions (in this case they are vetted, but not restricted conceptually). An example of a condition a user could specify may look like:

```
{"$and": [
  {"details.vulns": "cve-2019-19781"},
]}
```

This works well for searching, however, I want to be able to also generate statistics based on older data, for which I use an aggregation that looks something like:

```
db.hosts.aggregate([
    {"$sort": {"timestamp": 1}},
    {"$addFields": {
        "condition": {$cond: [
            {"$and": [
                {"details.vulns": "cve-2019-19781"},
            ]},
            1,
            0,
        ]}
    }},
    {"$project": {
        "ip":        "$ip",
        "timestamp": "$timestamp",
        "condition": "$condition",
    }},
]);
```

The problem with such a query is MongoDB does not seem to allow using a $cond with something like `$details.vulns`. I understand a standard approach would be to unwind, however, due to the conditions being not known before my code executes, I have no way to know what fields to unwind unless I re-implement a MongoDB parsing engine in my own code.

To demonstrate the issue more clearly, here is some example data. Keep in mind that this is simplified -- the real data contains many different fields that I may wish to query against, hence the above statements about unwind not being a satisfactory solution:

```
// Objects
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5cfc73657e2438b115888d1b"), "ip" : NumberLong("12345"), "timestamp" : ISODate("2019-06-09T02:45:45Z"), "vulns" : [ "cve-2019-19781" ] },
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d04c5497e2438b115b06659"), "ip" : NumberLong("12345"), "timestamp" : ISODate("2019-06-15T10:13:33Z"), "vulns" : [ "" ] },
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d108c52211d917c6ff48bfd"), "ip" : NumberLong("12345"), "timestamp" : ISODate("2019-06-24T08:37:31Z"), "vulns" : [ "cve-2019-19781", "other-vuln" ] },

// Desired output from aggregate
{"ip" : NumberLong("12345"), "timestamp" : ISODate("2019-06-09T02:45:45Z"), "condition": 1 },
{"ip" : NumberLong("12345"), "timestamp" : ISODate("2019-06-15T10:13:33Z"), "condition": 0 },
{"ip" : NumberLong("12345"), "timestamp" : ISODate("2019-06-24T08:37:31Z"), "condition": 1 },
```

Is there an alternative approach here I am missing, or does MongoDB simply lack the ability to apply a search clause during an aggregation?
If there was a slow way of doing it, I would be fine with that.

Comment: It will helpful if you add some sample document and expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Not clear what you are looking for. Do you mean this?

```
{"$addFields": {
    "condition": {$cond: [
        {$eq: ["$details.vulns": "cve-2019-19781"]},
        1,
        0,
    ]}
}},
```

Or a simple [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/index.html)?

You can run

```
var field = "ip";
db.hosts.aggregate([
  {$unwind: field }
])
```

or

```
var condObj = JSON.parse('{"$and": [{"details.vulns": "cve-2019-19781"}]}');
db.hosts.aggregate([
    {"$addFields": {
        "condition": {$cond: [
            condObj,
            1,
            0,
        ]}
    }}
]);
```

btw, you can simply write:

```
{"$project": {
    "ip": 1,
    "timestamp": 1,
    "condition": 1
}}
```

Comment: I've added more details to the question to hopefully help demonstrate the issue, also your first query fragment there gives me a syntax error when I attempt to run it.

Comment: Corrected the syntax error. For me it is still not clear what you are looking for. Why and when do you expect `1` or `0` for field `condition`?